# Installing devpi-client 4.1.0 fails in python2 virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, setuptools

Running `pip install devpi-client==4.1.0` in python2 virtual environment fails with below `Installing build dependencies ... error`:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /private/tmp/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/72/91vhtwlx2v577_2t46dkm6yh0000gq/T/pip-install-Owjkqu/setuptools/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/72/91vhtwlx2v577_2t46dkm6yh0000gq/T/pip-install-Owjkqu/setuptools/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/72/91vhtwlx2v577_2t46dkm6yh0000gq/T/pip-pip-egg-info-357GNw
       cwd: /private/var/folders/72/91vhtwlx2v577_2t46dkm6yh0000gq/T/pip-install-Owjkqu/setuptools/
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
      import setuptools.version
    File "setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
      import pkg_resources
    File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1365
      raise SyntaxError(e) from e
                              ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  -----------------------------
```

Above the error there are lines `Collecting setuptools>=42 Downloading .../setuptools-51.1.1.tar.gz (2.1 MB)`

`setuptools 51.1.1` [require minimum](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) python3.6, so it probably explains the syntax error.

Is there a way to force the package to use existing `setuptools` version or specify which version to use during build dependencies installation?